# Fluentd to OpenSearch: How to create dynamic indexes with K8s metadata?

Tags: kubernetes, logging, fluentd, opensearch, fluent-bit

I'm using the [fluent-operator](https://github.com/fluent/fluent-operator) to deploy fluentbit and fluentd.

Fluentbit collects and enriches the logs with Kubernetes metadata, then forwards to Fluentd.

Fluentd ships the logs to AWS OpenSearch.

I was trying to add a namespace label to the logstashPrefix like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: fluentd.fluent.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterOutput
metadata:
  name: cluster-fluentd-output-os
  labels:
    output.fluentd.fluent.io/scope: "cluster"
    output.fluentd.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
spec:
  outputs:
    - customPlugin:
        config: |
          <match **>
            @type opensearch
            host "${FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_HOST}"
            port 443
            logstash_format  true
            logstash_prefix logs-$${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']['labels']['org']}
            scheme https
            <endpoint>
              url "https://${FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_HOST}"
              region "${FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_REGION}"
              assume_role_arn "#{ENV['AWS_ROLE_ARN']}"
              assume_role_web_identity_token_file "#{ENV['AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE']}"
            </endpoint>
          </match>
      logLevel: info
```

But it ended up creating an index with the Ruby expression in it:

`logs-${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']['labels']['org']}-2023.04.04`

This is because fluentbit doesn't enrich the logs with namespace metadata besides the namespace name. Here's an example log:

```
{
  "_index": "logs-${record['kubernetes']['pod_name']}-2023.04.04",
  "_id": "XXX-XXX",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "log": "2023-04-04T22:19:06.572970297Z stdout F Notice: XXXX for 'XXXX'",
    "kubernetes": {
      "pod_name": "dockerhub-limit-exporter-XXX-XXX",
      "namespace_name": "observability-system",
      "labels": {
        "app.kubernetes.io/instance": "dockerhub-limit-exporter",
        "app.kubernetes.io/name": "dockerhub-limit-exporter",
        "pod-template-hash": "XXX"
      },
      "annotations": {
        "kubernetes.io/psp": "eks.privileged"
      },
      "container_name": "dockerhub-limit-exporter",
      "docker_id": "XXXX",
      "container_image": "XXX.XXX.XXX.com/XXX/docker-hub-limit-exporter:0.0.0"
    },
    "@timestamp": "2023-04-04T22:19:06.576573487+00:00"
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      "2023-04-04T22:19:06.576Z"
    ]
  },
  "highlight": {
    "kubernetes.namespace_name": [
      "@opensearch-dashboards-highlighted-field@observability@/opensearch-dashboards-highlighted-field@-@opensearch-dashboards-highlighted-field@system@/opensearch-dashboards-highlighted-field@"
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1680646746576
  ]
}
```

This my actual fluentbit and fluentd configuration:

```yaml
apiVersion: fluentbit.fluent.io/v1alpha2
kind: FluentBit
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluent-bit
  name: fluent-bit
  namespace: fluent-system
spec:
  affinity:
    nodeAffinity:
      requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/edge
            operator: DoesNotExist
  fluentBitConfigName: fluent-bit-config
  image: kubesphere/fluent-bit:${FLUENTBIT_IMAGE_TAG:=v2.0.9}
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: image-pull-secret
  positionDB:
    hostPath:
      path: /var/lib/fluent-bit/
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: ${FLUENTBIT_CPU_LIMIT:=500m}
      memory: ${FLUENTBIT_MEMORY_LIMIT:=200Mi}
    requests:
      cpu: ${FLUENTBIT_CPU_REQUEST:=10m}
      memory: ${FLUENTBIT_MEMORY_REQUEST:=25Mi}
  tolerations:
  - operator: Exists
---
apiVersion: fluentbit.fluent.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterInput
metadata:
  labels:
    fluentbit.fluent.io/component: logging
    fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  name: tail
spec:
  tail:
    db: /fluent-bit/tail/pos.db
    dbSync: Normal
    memBufLimit: ${FLUENTBIT_MEM_BUF_LIMIT:=5MB}
    parser: docker
    path: /var/log/containers/*.log
    refreshIntervalSeconds: 10
    skipLongLines: true
    tag: kube.*
---
apiVersion: fluentbit.fluent.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterInput
metadata:
  labels:
    fluentbit.fluent.io/component: logging
    fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  name: docker
spec:
  systemd:
    db: /fluent-bit/tail/systemd.db
    dbSync: Normal
    path: /var/log/journal
    systemdFilter:
    - _SYSTEMD_UNIT=docker.service
    - _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service
    tag: service.*
---
apiVersion: fluentbit.fluent.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterFluentBitConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluent-bit
  name: fluent-bit-config
spec:
  filterSelector:
    matchLabels:
      fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  inputSelector:
    matchLabels:
      fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  outputSelector:
    matchLabels:
      fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  service:
    parsersFile: parsers.conf
---
apiVersion: fluentbit.fluent.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterFilter
metadata:
  labels:
    fluentbit.fluent.io/component: logging
    fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  name: kubernetes
spec:
  filters:
  - kubernetes:
      annotations: true
      kubeCAFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
      kubeTokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
      kubeURL: https://kubernetes.default.svc:443
      labels: true
  - nest:
      addPrefix: kubernetes_
      nestedUnder: kubernetes
      operation: lift
  - modify:
      rules:
      - remove: stream
      - remove: kubernetes_pod_id
      - remove: kubernetes_host
      - remove: kubernetes_container_hash
  - nest:
      nestUnder: kubernetes
      operation: nest
      removePrefix: kubernetes_
      wildcard:
      - kubernetes_*
  match: kube.*
---
apiVersion: fluentbit.fluent.io/v1alpha2
kind: ClusterOutput
metadata:
  labels:
    fluentbit.fluent.io/component: logging
    fluentbit.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  name: fluentd
spec:
  forward:
    host: fluentd.fluent-system.svc
    port: 24224
  matchRegex: (?:kube|service)\.(.*)
---
apiVersion: fluentd.fluent.io/v1alpha1
kind: Fluentd
metadata:
  name: fluentd
  namespace: fluent-system
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: fluentd
spec:
  globalInputs:
    - forward:
        bind: 0.0.0.0
        port: 24224
  replicas: 1
  image: kubesphere/fluentd:${FLUENTD_IMAGE_TAG:=v1.15.3}
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: image-pull-secret
  resources:
    limits:
      cpu: ${FLUENTD_CPU_LIMIT:=500m}
      memory: ${FLUENTD_MEMORY_LIMIT:=500Mi}
    requests:
      cpu: ${FLUENTD_CPU_REQUEST:=100m}
      memory: ${FLUENTD_MEMORY_REQUEST:=128Mi}
  fluentdCfgSelector:
    matchLabels:
      config.fluentd.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
---
apiVersion: fluentd.fluent.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterFluentdConfig
metadata:
  labels:
    config.fluentd.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  name: fluentd-config
spec:
  clusterFilterSelector:
    matchLabels:
      filter.fluentd.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  clusterOutputSelector:
    matchLabels:
      output.fluentd.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
  watchedNamespaces: [] # watches all namespaces when empty
---
apiVersion: fluentd.fluent.io/v1alpha1
kind: ClusterOutput
metadata:
  name: cluster-fluentd-output-os
  labels:
    output.fluentd.fluent.io/scope: "cluster"
    output.fluentd.fluent.io/enabled: "true"
spec:
  outputs:
    - customPlugin:
        config: |
          <match **>
            @type opensearch
            host "${FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_HOST}"
            port 443
            logstash_format  true
            logstash_prefix logs-$${record['kubernetes']['namespace_name']['labels']['org']}
            scheme https
            <endpoint>
              url "https://${FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_HOST}"
              region "${FLUENT_OPENSEARCH_REGION}"
              assume_role_arn "#{ENV['AWS_ROLE_ARN']}"
              assume_role_web_identity_token_file "#{ENV['AWS_WEB_IDENTITY_TOKEN_FILE']}"
            </endpoint>
          </match>
      logLevel: info
```

**How can dynamic indexing with k8s metadata be achieved leveraging the fluent-operator features?**